# How to add AppTitle to NavigationView

Tags: c#, uwp

Is installed the Fall update and tried out the [Navigation View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) control. Seems close enough to the Hamburger control from the UWP toolkit.

But i am having trouble adding a custom app title to the page. The directions in the article are kinda unclear to me:

> Drawing into the title bar has the side-effect of hiding your app's title. To help users, restore the title by adding your own TextBlock. Add the following markup to the root page containing your NavigationView.

This is followed by this xaml:

```
<!-- Page attribute -->
xmlns:appmodel="using:Windows.ApplicationModel"

<TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind appmodel:Package.Current.DisplayName}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
```

So i thought i'd drop this XAML code inside my Pages grid, but i don't get an App Title. Where do i need to drop this code to make it work?

Heres my page xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="MyPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:appmodel="using:Windows.ApplicationModel"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind appmodel:Package.Current.DisplayName}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

    <NavigationView>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
            <ContentControl  />
        </Frame>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TextBlock is hidden behind your NavigationView. This is more obvious if you have a long enough title that it extends past the Nav Pane:

[image]

You can put it on top by switching the order in Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
            <ContentControl  />
        </Frame>
    </NavigationView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind appmodel:Package.Current.DisplayName}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```